# App view feels like it's "LAGGING"

Tags: iphone, uitableview, controls, cells

Most of the views in my app are UITableVlews inside a UIViewController. My App feels like it's lagging when trying to scroll through the tables. I was wondering (1.) if it is better to create the cell objects in the table view, or create them at runtime and add them to the cells subview?

**examples**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            case 3: 
            {
                NSNumber *tetherState = [[mobIntDict objectForKey:@"State"] intValue];
                NSNumber *currValState = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:1023] intValue];
                tetherSw = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(197, 8, 94, 27)];
                tetherSw.tag = kDefaultSwTag;
                if(tetherState == currValState){
                    tetherSw.on = YES;
                }else{
                    tetherSw.on = NO;
                }
                [tetherSw addTarget:self action:@selector(tetherSwAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:tetherSw];
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Tether";
                [tetherSw release];
            }
                break;
}
```

-**OR**-

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    tetherSw = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(197, 8, 94, 27)] autorelease];
    tetherSw.tag = kDefaultSwTag;
    [tetherSw addTarget:self action:@selector(tetherSwAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            case 3: 
            {
                 [cell addSubView:tetherSw];
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my tables are setup just fine. A solid restore did the trick, and my app runs without the afore-mentioned "LAG"

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. Your cell is complex and therefore your view lags.

If you want performance, avoid the `UISwitch`. Toggle the cell's checkmark instead. In fact, just avoid any fancy table view cell subclasses or custom backgrounds, to reduce the size of the view hierarchy.

Comment: thats kind of the main functionality of my app is depending on the UISwitches. As for backgrounds, I dont have any set, just normal TV bg.

Answer (score 1):

Are you properly de-queuing and reusing cells?

It would optimise things a lot if you reused a cell, say a @"SwitchCell", that would speed up scrolling a lot. Currently a lot of time will be spent adding the switch to the cell's content view (laying out of views etc,) and performing other tasks that only need to happen once in a cells lifetime, instead of every time a new cell appears while scrolling.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Create cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SwitchCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UISwitch *tetherSw = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(197, 8, 94, 27)];
        tetherSw.tag = kDefaultSwTag;
        [tetherSw addTarget:self action:@selector(tetherSwAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tetherSw];
        [tetherSw release];
    }

    // Setup for each cell
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Tether";
    NSNumber *tetherState = [[mobIntDict objectForKey:@"State"] intValue];
    NSNumber *currValState = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:1023] intValue];
    UISwitch *tetherSw = (UISwitch *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: kDefaultSwTag];
    tetherSw.on = (tetherState == currValState);

    // Return
    return cell;

}
```

See the docs for [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:) for more information on dequeuing.

Also, make sure that there is no transparency in any of your cell's subviews. This causes a lot of lagging. Make sure any labels or anything else you add has `opaque = YES` and a background color set.